# How to Convert this Inline CSS to External CSS using just a single class?

Tags: html, css

I have some requirement that needed to convert the given inline css element to external css using just my-control class, [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pgfUT/1/),

```
    <div class="control my-control">
        <div style="float: left;">
            <div style="padding-left: 3px; padding-top: 3px;">
                <div style="float: left;">Title:</div>
                <div style="float: left; padding-left: 12px"></div>
                <div style="clear: both"></div>
            </div>
            <div style="padding-left: 3px; padding-top: 3px;">
                <div style="float: left;">Lyrics:    </div>
                <div style="float: left; padding-left: 3px">
                    <div style="overflow: hidden; width: 180px; white-space: nowrap;" class="lyric-content"></div>
                </div>
                <div style="clear: both"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="float: right; border-left: 1px solid black;">
            <img src="Content/Images/play.png" style="height: 50px;"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: whats wrong in multiple class ?

Comment: @NullPointer, I am creating some controls internally. I have to only use one parent class.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek, I am trying in Fiddle and using different combinations of ~ + > and finding lot of difficulties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/pgfUT/4/

```
.control.my-control {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 15px;
    width: 300px;    
}

.control.my-control > div {
    float: left;    
}

.control.my-control > div + div {
    float: right;
    border-left: 1px solid black;    
}

.control.my-control > div + div > img {
    height: 50px;
}

.control.my-control > div > div {
    padding-left: 3px;
    padding-top: 3px;
}

.control.my-control > div > div > div {
    float: left;
}

.control.my-control > div > div > div:last-child {
    float: none;
    clear: both;
}

.control.my-control > div > div > div + div {
    padding-left: 12px;
}

.control.my-control > div > div + div > div + div {
    padding-left: 3px;
}

.control.my-control > div > div > div > div.lyric-content {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 180px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

​